# host name setting in IBM Web Sphere Application Server Liberty Profile ver 17.0.0.2

Tags: ibm-cloud, virtualhost, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I installed IBM TRIRIGA Application Platform 10.5.3 in Linux CentOs7. While installing TRIRIGA installer, I selected embedded server that is IBM Web Sphere Application Server Liberty Profile 17.0.0.2. Server is successfully installed and up and running.

From the Log I found that server host where IBM Tririga is accessable is some thing like URL : http://some.static.ab-xyz.com:8001. This is taken by default. I have not provided this value.

My question is :How to change this url host name ? Where is setting for this?

Thanks
Kumar Shorav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Liberty server will have a server.xml file which contains the configuration for the server.  I'm not sure where Tririga embeds Liberty or its server.xml, but if you can locate this file you should see an entry like this:

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="8001"/>
```

This the attribute `host="*"` will configure the HTTP endpoint to listen on all available network interfaces that the physical machine is running on (e.g. `localhost` and `some.static.ab-xyz.com`).  If you want to make a you server available at a custom hostname such as `my-website.com`, you would need to register with a DNS provider.

Comment: Yea, I saw this file. So if i change "*" with IP, it should be accessible right?

Comment: No, * means it is listening on all local interfaces. Those interfaces have 1 or more IP addresses already associated with them.  The server is finding 1 of potentially many hostnames that one of these addresses reverse-resolves to at startup.

If it already says *, use any hostname that reaches that systems IP address to access the server..